# Wordpress Pages in an Array

Tags: loop

I'm trying to get all the page names that is in the WordPress website and store it an array so I can pass it to Visual Composer in a short code.

I cannot figure out where I am going wrong

```
$pages = get_pages(); 
$r=array();
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $r[$page->post_name];

}
return $r;
```

Comment: Looks like you're not assigning any values to the empty $r array. This is a pure PHP problem so I vote to close it.

Comment: Change `$r[$page->post_name];` to `$r[] = $page->post_name;`

Answer (score 0):

Your changes `$r[$page->post_name]; to $r[] = $page->post_name;` are working fine when I checked them

Instead of `return $r;` use `print_r($r)`

You should see the list of all your pages. Also could you describe why you are using `return $r`

Comment: Thanks works now. :-) Been staring at the code for hours

Comment: Good to know. Don't forget to marked it as answered ;)